# Higher order multipolar second harmonic generation in centrosymmetric materials

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, non-linear-optics, multipole-expansion

As is pointed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127531/lack-of-inversion-symmetry-in-crystal) question, second harmonic generation is forbidden **in the bulk** of the materials possessing centrosymmetry. In some papers it is said that in the dipolar approximation the SHG vanishes, and if we consider **magnetic dipoles or electric quadrupole** terms or other higher order multipole terms, they can generate second harmonic.

I was not sure what do they mean by this. How do we consider various multipole terms of the field here? I know that the optical nonlinearities are expressed with the expansion of the polarization vector of the material (which means *dipole*):
$$P=P_0+\epsilon_0 \chi^{(1)} E+\epsilon_0 \chi^{(2)} E^2 +\epsilon_0 \chi^{(3)} E^3 +...$$

but don't know **how the similar expansions can exist for the higher order multipoles**.