# Curious question about light and photons

Tags: visible-light, photons, doppler-effect

If a photon wavelength (e.g., yellow) is isolated from the other wavelengths that the sun emits (once it gets to earth), can that particular particle/photon be distorted slightly into a wavelength that is shorter (e.g., perceived as green)?

If yes; please explain.
If no; please explain.

Thank you!

Comment: If you run toward the yellow photon at 10% the speed of light, [it will become green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift#Doppler_effect).

Comment: 1. Can you separate/isolate certain wavelengths of light from the total spectrum that our star gives off (after that light goes through our atmosphere)?

2. If that isolated light has a wavelength of about 570 nm (yellow) can it be manipulated or distorted to equal a slightly shorter wavelength of about 510 nm (green)?

Please explain why if yes or no, if possible.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

I transform the wavelengths of light everyday in the laboratory; so do you if you have a green laser pointer. For how a green laser pointer works, see http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/laserpic/glpdpics.htm

This is called non-linear optics, and requires (a) higher than normal intensity of light, and (b) a properly cut crystal that meets specific structural requirements.

So if you want to convert yellow light to green light you will have to work harder, because the simplest processes change the wavelength by a factor of 2: double it, generating two new photons from each one destroyed, or divide it in half, which requires two photons to be destroyed while creating one replacement with double the energy (half the wavelength).

This was first demonstrated by Peter Franken, et al, at the University of Michigan, in 1961. The paper is discussed here, with references: http://www.laserfocusworld.com/articles/2011/09/sprc-symposium-2011.html

Comment: Peter, this is fantastic, ill begin some research here.

Comment: I have a question about your laser transformations.  Is there a way to transform the wavelengths without losing energy or using artificial means, by only using the suns light separated and then routed to a medium that might shorten its length without added electricity to the process?

Comment: No energy is consumed in this parametric wavelength shifting; however,  it is often quite inefficient.   I'm currently doing down conversion,  splitting one 402 nm photon into a pair of 804 nm photons - but it only converts 1 per 100,000,000 possibles. The green laser pointer is much more efficient, and the article explains why in detail.

Comment: Mr Diehr, how do we do to increase the frequency directly ?

Comment: In theory one can have high enough power to disrupt the vacuum; my thesis advisor was interested in this and every extremely high power density application.  In practice, it takes a mediator, such as a centrosymmetric crystal,  like BBO, though with high enough power even a magnetic field can be used, along with a collision.  It's all in the statistics.

Comment: I worked ( from far ) with a team trying to treat datacenters heat. Many heavy technics work but they only change a little bit the spectrum distribution. There is something to do about this problem :) Thank you

Comment: Peter, can you please elaborate and explain a bit more?

Comment: say 1200, 1100, 1000,..., 600 respectively in wavelengths of light i wish to capture from a source that emits also 1300, 1400, ... on down. collectively they equal 700 units (%) that i wish to focus on.
Lets say i disperse the light at 1200, using (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_upconversion) or another method we havent touched on here, i split the wavelenth to 600, say 5% of that light makes it to 600. Then i do that for the whole lot of frequencies below and higher. violated the conservation laws if the frequencies from 600 on up to ultraviolet range are more intense than  previous?

Comment: Nonlinear optical effects are intensity dependent; that is, the greater the intensity of the light brought to bear on the crystal, the greater the conversion efficiency.  For continuous beams the efficiency may increase as the length of the crystal increases, but this doesn't work in cases where "phase matching" is required.  For greatest efficiency you would have to separate the wavelengths, such as by diffraction, and process each group with its own optimal process.  Upconversion increases the frequency (and energy) of the remaining photons, while reducing their wavelengths.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of being able to change one frequency (it's a bit more correct in this context to use frequency rather than wavelength) into another is a question of linearity. Generally, the equations that govern light/optics (Maxwell's equations) are considered linear. This has the implication that any light you start with at one frequency will stay at the same frequency forever.

To change frequencies, it's necessary for light to interact non linearly. The short of it is that light will generally only act nonlinearly in materials, and only if your light has sufficient power. This is usually seen only in [certain crystals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127531/lack-of-inversion-symmetry-in-crystal), but can happen in any material if your light is sufficiently strong.

Comment: David,  lets suppose i went outside and used a monochromator to filter out every frequency except my desired frequency/wavelength.  Lets say the wavelength is 700nm from peak to peak.  Could i run that frequency through a material to make it 699.999 nm peak to peak?  699nm peak to peak? what about  350nm peak to peak?  Someone pointed me towards this article (http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/laserpic/glpdpics.htm) In this article the laser uses a KTP intracavity frequency doubler crystal to emit a green light that is half its original wavelength. Could this be done without adding energy to source?

Comment: Realistically, it would be very difficult to separate 700nm light from 699.99nm light, or even 699nm light. If you were to somehow separate out precisely 700nm light, you would see "broadening" effects, where new wavelengths in a small range above and below 700nm are generated. One cause of this is photons can gain or lose energy from small vibrations in the material they pass through. To generate new wavelengths through nonlinear effects, there's also a conservation of energy rule $f_1+f_2=f_3$. For 700nm to 699nm, this implies combining 700nm light with 0.6THz light, which isn't feasible.

Comment: David, can you elaborate on photons gaining energy from small vibrations in material they pass through?  Which materials?  My question was just to pinpoint the concept, its not necessary for this application to separate such fine wavelengths, but that raises a question of why can't we isolate the separate frequencies of light at that small a wavelength peak to peak when we can so easily isolate them at lower frequencies?

Comment: say 1200, 1100, 1000,..., 600 respectively in wavelengths of light i wish to capture from a source that emits also 1300, 1400, ... on down. collectively they equal 700 units (%) that i wish to focus on.
Lets say i disperse the light at 1200, using (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_upconversion) or another method we havent touched on here, i split the wavelenth to 600, say 5% of that light makes it to 600. Then i do that for the whole lot of frequencies below and higher. violated the conservation laws if the frequencies from 600 on up to ultraviolet range are more intense than  previous?

Answer (score 0):

Interacting photons (Compton scattering)  with electrons at rest is a non linear process that decreases  light frequency (yellow to red).
Also , reflecting photons in a finite mass mirror decreases the frequency of photons as some momentum is transferred to mirror.
So it is no possible for a cold plasma or metal to increase the frequency of photons in order to promote them from yellow to green.