# Why there is no even order in high-order harmonics generation of noble gas?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, coherence

As we all know, there is no even-order peaks in HHG of noble gas. I understand this phenomenon by the knowledge [here](https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/chab/physical-chemistry/ultrafast-spectroscopy-dam/documents/lectures/spectroscopyFS13/projectsFS13/HHG_Instructions.pdf): there will be odd and even peaks in the frequency domain when we do fourier transform on a series of equally seperated pulses in time domain. Then the even order peaks dispear because that the even-order nonlinear susceptbility of noble gas is zero. However, the present explanation is really ugly. Is there more direct and resonable understanding of this phenomenon?

Comment: Why don't you like this explanation? The even order nonlinear susceptibility is equal to zero for symmetry reasons (a noble gas can be considered as a centrosymmetric medium) and this is the reason why even peaks are not obtained!

Comment: @JackI Because this explanation looks like two patchs for a bug. It makes me feel that it doesn't come from the very basic physics.

Comment: It is due to the symmetry of the interaction term between the laser field and the atom as shown in https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vitali_Averbukh/publication/242200024_Selection_Rules_for_the_High_Harmonic_Generation_Spectra/links/55141f630cf23203199cda8a/Selection-Rules-for-the-High-Harmonic-Generation-Spectra.pdf.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127531/lack-of-inversion-symmetry-in-crystal

Answer (score 0):

Selection rules in the spectrum correspond directly with symmetries in the time domain.

For the case of even harmonics in HHG (or indeed *any* harmonic-generation configuration), the driving laser has a symmetry of the form
$$ E(t+\pi/\omega) = - E(t)$$
(i.e. advancing time by half a period results in a spatially-inverted electric field) and for a noble gas the generating medium is symmetric under that inversion, which entails that the dipole moment of the harmonic emission shares that symmetry,
$$ D(t+\pi/\omega) = - D(t).$$
The lack of even harmonic orders is simply the Fourier transform of this property.