# No even-order harmonics in alkali gases? (Intuition for “symmetry in time domain'')

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-optics, non-linear-systems

The polarizability can be expanded in the from:
[image]

In Alkali gases, it is said that $\chi^3$ can be nonzero, and the combination of multiple waves can produce four-wave-mixing.

But what about $\chi^2$?
I've heard it said that even order harmonics typically don't occur in gases because of "symmetries in the time domain," as said [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445088/why-there-is-no-even-order-in-high-order-harmonics-generation-of-noble-gas).

What does this mean exactly? To try to articulate my interpretation of this:
[image]
Am I understanding correctly that the statement is that processes like this are forbidden? If that interpetation is correct, why is that the case?

Comment: Harmonics in the expansion of what quantity?

Comment: @G.Smith, "harmonics" in quantum optics often refer to when light is turned into new light that is an integer multiple in frequency of the electric field (so a second order harmonic would mean the light that underwent a process that had its frequency doubled)