# Furry's theorem and spontaneous parametric down-conversion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

In spontaneous parametric down-conversion, a single photon interacts with a nonlinear medium to produce a pair of lower energy photons. It is observed that energy, momentum, and orbital-angular-momentum are conserved in the process. However, I have seen arguments invoking Furry's theorem (see https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~fionn/qft/furry.pdf) stating that it is not possible for a photon to get destroyed to produce two photons. What is the key insight that I am missing here?

Comment: Somewhat related: [“Lack of inversion symmetry” in crystal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127531/lack-of-inversion-symmetry-in-crystal).

Answer (score 4):

The theorem you've linked to is true - *in vacuum*.

SPDC happens in a non-linear medium which breaks the symmetries that underlie the hypotheses of that theorem. As such, there is no contradiction between the two.

Comment: I suspect there is something more because the process involves a single free photon at initial time, a finite interaction for a finite time, and then two free photons. As the process is parametric, there is no net transfer of energy, momentum, or angular momentum to the nonlinear medium. So if I look at the system only at the initial and final times as a unitary scattering process, I am not sure how the nonlinearity alone can rescue the process from the verdict of Furry's theorem.

Comment: Moreover, the nonlinear medium is also electromagnetic in nature. So although the medium does not possess spatial inversion symmetry, it does possess charge conjugation symmetry. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Unless the medium is a positronium crystal, or something similar, then it certainly does not possess charge-conjugation symmetry. (Hint: if it has electrons but it doesn't have positrons, then it's $C$-asymmetric.) But that's not really necessary - the lack of inversion symmetry is sufficient.