# Inversion symmetry for Second Harmonic Generation

Tags: optics, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, non-linear-optics, harmonics

I read this question ["Lack of inversion symmetry" in crystal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127531/lack-of-inversion-symmetry-in-crystal/127567), but it is not quite clear to me how to clearly define the symmetry. Let me explain with a simple example. In the image below you see the "L" shape which is not symmetric under inversion. However, if two "L" shapes are arranged like shown, we have a symmetry again.
So what would that mean for a material build up like that, would it show Second harmonic signal ?[image]

Comment: that way we would never have symmetry breaking. If you always take the mirror image and glue it to the original building block, now you have something symmetric (of course there would be exceptions like penrose-type tilings). I think its easier to think about the potential well of the system rather than the lattice itself. See the answer by Steve Byrnes in the posted question. Basically a non-symmetric potential arises from a non-symmetrical unit cell. And regarding your image, if your unit cell is the L, then thats what you need to consider and what "shapes" the potential well.

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting. Maybe my questions points in another direction: If Ithink now of a macroscopic material with the first few 100nm made up from molecules/unit cells with the "L" shape and the last few 100nm made up from the upside down "L". For each part I guess, I would get a SH signal. And with your argumentation I would not get a signal for a macroscopic material with molecules of the shape "L+mirror image". So it means I need to consider the "size" of the electrical field, right ?

Comment: why would a material (that was the same) have 2 regions with different unit cells? So, like I said, you need to consider the unit cell and how that shapes your potential wells, because that's where the electrons oscillate and create polarization of the medium. As soon as you have more than a unit cell, you have many potential wells, and not only the representative one. The wells arise from a quasi-infinite stack of unit cells, but the unit cell still determines the overall shape of the well.

Comment: Oh I meant not one material, but a bilayer for example. The bilayer itself would be symmetric under rotation, whereas each single layer would not. But I got your point, I think. It is about the symmetry of the potential, the electron sits in and not the symmetry of the system as a whole.